# SQLAlchemy Linear One-to-One Relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, one-to-one

I have two classes mapped to two tables respectively.

**Ex:**
`Obj 1: ID (PK), KEY (String(20))`
`Obj 2: ID (PK), obj_1_id (FK), value (String(20))`

I would like to be able to perform `obj_1.value = *val*`, whereby *val* is stored on the secon'd table's respective column, **instead of** obj_1.value.value = *val*`.

- How can I create such relationship, spread/mapped to two tables' columns?

What I want is **not** one-to-one (object HAS object) but rather map **a column** of an object to a different table.

Following is what I have tried (following the docs) and it does not work as it creates `obj1.value.value = ..` instead of direct column mapping

**What I have tried:**

```
class Obj1(Base):

    __tablename__ == ...

    id = ..
    key = ..

    value = relationship("Obj2", uselist=False, backref="obj1")

class Obj2(Base):

    __tablename__ == ...

    id = ..       # PK
    obj_1_id = .. # FK

    value = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just wrap the python property:

```
class Obj1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'obj1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = Column(String(20))

    _value_rel = relationship("Obj2", uselist=False, backref="obj1")

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value_rel and self._value_rel.value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            self._value_rel = None
        elif self._value_rel is None:
            self._value_rel = Obj2(value=value)
        else:
            self._value_rel.value = value
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It solves the problem but feels a bit complex. Shouldn't there be (or isn't there) a simpler way to do this kind of mapping with SA?

Comment: You are free to write you own construct/wrapper to hide all the `complexity`.